# nginx disable gzip only for facebook crawler

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, nginx

Sharing Debugger is not fetching proper data from my site and I found that the problem is `gzip`.

Can i disable gzip for nginx only for Facebook crawler?

`Inferred Property
The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Object Missing a Required Value
Object at URL 'https://kida.al/13' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler) , the Facebook Crawler will identify itself as "facebookexternalhit". Therefore you can disable gzip for that user agent. Something like this might work (note, this was not tested)

```
server {
  (all settings here)

  location ~ / { 
    if ($http_user_agent ~ facebookexternalhit) {
      gzip off;
    }  // End iff
  }  // End Location
}  // End Server
```

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS I get this error: `nginx: [emerg] "gzip" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:90`

Comment: According to http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html , the gzip directive is allowed in http, server, location and if in location. You'll need to move the "if" block inside a "location" block for it to work.

Comment: I put it inside `http` and now the error is `nginx: [emerg] "if" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:61
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`

Comment: You'll need to put the "if" inside a "location" block.

Comment: If I put this inside http I get: `nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:57
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`

If I put inside server syntax is ok but things get really bad. `404 Not Found`

In both cases it is inside `location / {
  if ($http_user_agent ~ facebookexternalhit) {
            gzip off;
        }
 }`

Comment: The blocks go in this order: http , server, location, if. You need to put if inside location. Location inside server. Server inside http.

Comment: the config files are separated by default. it works fine if I do not put those lines